# Why other wizarding schools of Europe didn't participate in Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-2, the-goblet-of-fire

In the event of Triwizard Tournament, a magical contest held between the three largest wizarding schools of Europe: Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, Durmstrang Institute, and Beauxbatons Academy of Magic.

Also at Yule ball, when Hermione replied back to Ron when he refuses to join her and Krum for drinks:

> The enemy? Who was it wanting his autograph? Besides, the whole point of the tournament is international magical cooperation, to make friends!

Why didn't these schools help Hogwarts to fight against Voldemort in the Battle of Hogwarts?

Comment: Related on SFF: [Why did international wizards not come to help against Voldemort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58575/70236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it is neither explained in books nor movies why other schools didn't participate in this battle. But here is a theory.

Voldemort only returned to Hogwarts because he came to know that what was Harry and his friends up to and that Harry was in Hogwarts. His ultimate aim was to kill Harry and rule the wizard world.

The battle of Hogwarts last for one or two days. And the entire school tried to defend Harry and to help him complete his quest.

There was no need for Voldemort to come at Hogwarts as it was already under control.

Also Dumbledore was busy hunting Hocruxes and didn't get time to raise awareness about this. After he was killed, the Ministry or Magic and Hogwarts was under control of Voldemort and therefore, who might have thought of fighting before may have dropped this idea to stay safe.

Since other schools had nothing to do with the war, they wouldn't have considered getting involved in that. Also what kind of motivation would their students have to help out students in a different country.

Though Dumbledore indirectly called others to help in his speech in the end of Goblet of Fire.

> "Every guest in this Hall," said Dumbledore, and his eyes lingered upon the Durmstrang students, "will be welcomed back here at any time, should they wish to come. I say to you all, once again -- in the light of Lord Voldemort's return, we are only as strong as we are united, as weak as we are divided. Lord Voldemort's gift for spreading discord and enmity is very great. We can fight it only by showing an equally strong bond of friendship and trust. Differences of habit and language are nothing at all if our aims are identical and our hearts are open.

Comment: They also may be too scared to face Voldemort.

Comment: You say other schools had nothing to do with the war, but didn't Voldemort pose a large threat to the entire wizarding world? Surely after witnessing the events of the Tri Wiz Tourney and Dumbedore's speech, the other schools' headmasters and students would surely be inclined to lend a hand?

Comment: @ZipZapJ Ok. I think you missed second and third paragraphs.

Comment: I never thought about this, but now it feels like a missed opportunity on Rowling's part.

Comment: @ViggyNash I always felt like Rowling missed tons of opportunities. First thing was to make all 3 main characters Gryffindor instead of exploring her own creation and put Hermione in Ravenclaw where she clearly belongs. Also, I don't se why Ron shouldn't be Hufflepuff.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true! Madame Maxime (Head-mistress of Beauxbatons) did accompany Hagrid on his quest to enlist the help of the giants on Dumbledore's orders. That's how he is absent from Hogwarts for the initial portion of the 5th part. They have not covered this in the movie unfortunately.